# Tkinter - Python : Changing background color

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, background-color

```
[Person: Ahmet] is very handsome . He is working at [Organization: Zara] , their family live in [Location: Istanbul]


Person: 1
Location: 1
Organization: 1
```

i have a text output like that and i show this in tkinter text .
i want to change my background colors like that:

```
[Person: anyword] # yellow
[Organization: anyword] #green
[Location: anyword] #orange
```

How can i create a tag configuration ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import os.path
import io
import subprocess as sub

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import csv
import subprocess

from tkFileDialog import *


class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.text = Text()
    self.text1 = Text()
    self.text.pack()
    self.text1.pack()

        menu = Menu(master)
        root.config(menu=menu)
        # file menu
        filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Browse Text File", menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New")
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.file_open)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=self.file_save)        
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.do_exit)

    def file_open(self):
        """open a file to read"""
        # optional initial directory (default is current directory)
        initial_dir = "C:\Temp"
        # the filetype mask (default is all files)
        mask = \
        [("Text and Python files","*.txt"), 
        ("HTML files","*.htm"), 
        ("All files","*.*")]        
        fin = askopenfile(initialdir=initial_dir, filetypes=mask, mode='r')
        text = fin.read()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ner.py',  str(askopenfilename())], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        if text != None:
            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(END,text)
        self.text1.delete(0.0, END)
        self.text1.insert(END,proc.communicate()[0])



    def file_save(self):
        """get a filename and save the text in the editor widget"""
        # default extension is optional, here will add .txt if missing
        fout = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
        text2save = str(self.text.get(0.0,END))
        fout.write(text2save)
        fout.close()

    def do_exit(self):
        root.destroy()



root = Tk()
root.title("Named Entity Recognizer (TR)")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

First i show the original text and second i show the edited text which found ner types. I know it works with tag configure but how can i add the words inside the brackets. Thanks for helping.

text.tag_config("[Person: ??]", background="yellow", foreground="red")

Answer (score 0):

Copied this from the interwebs somewhere

```
def color_text(edit, tag, word, fg_color='black', bg_color='white'):
    # add a space to the end of the word
    word = word + " "
    edit.insert('end', word)
    end_index = edit.index('end')
    begin_index = "%s-%sc" % (end_index, len(word) + 1)
    edit.tag_add(tag, begin_index, end_index)
    edit.tag_config(tag, foreground=fg_color, background=bg_color)


# pick word to be colored
myword1 = 'Jack'
myword2 = 'Jill'
# create a list of unique tags
tags = ["tg" + str(k) for k in range(len(word_list))]
for ix, word in enumerate(word_list):
    # word[:len(myword)] for word ending with a punctuation mark
    if word[:len(myword1)] == myword1:
        color_text(edit, tags[ix], word, 'blue')
    elif word[:len(myword2)] == myword2:
        color_text(edit, tags[ix], word, 'red', 'yellow')
    else:
        color_text(edit, tags[ix], word)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do here is create a Tkinter Canvas. I'm not sure of the exact syntax in python 2 because I use 3, but that will only result in minor changes:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg='red') #change the color at bg
c.pack()
c.mainloop()
```

You can change the Canvas color with a variable according to your output. Where it says `bg='red'`, that's where you change the color.
Please tell me if I've got python 2 incorrect syntax, hope this helps!